# CakePHP - upgrade from Mysql to MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, mariadb

I have few website in CakePHP 2.4, and have to upgrade its Mysql API to MariaDB API, I am wondering if CakePHP 2.4 support MariaDB natively? Or I have to install some extension for PHP, and change CakePHP a little bit, hope someone can give me some advice, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As I was googling, and I fond this - https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/, so their driver, API is same.

**All MySQL connectors (PHP, Perl, Python, Java, .NET, MyODBC, Ruby, MySQL C connector etc) work unchanged with MariaDB.
There are some installation issues with PHP5 that you should be aware of (a bug in how the old PHP5 client checks library compatibility).**